# How to create nested json from codable model in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, nested

I have been trying to create json from model. Initially created aadhar model and stored aadhar data from api response to model.

And created another aadhar model2, passed aadhar model value to aadhar model2. But aadhar model 1 and aadhar model 2 response differ parameters.

here is my json response value.

```
{
"apiVersion": "1.3.1",
"id": "387a65ba6e51cd1d18bef58cc60c47b751830532ea10465106a54d600d5042f9",
"data": {
    "meta": {
        "confidence_ocr_mean": 0.95869,
        "confidence_ocr_var": 0.00912,
        "confidence_ocr_skew": -4.06817,
        "confidence_ocr_kurt": 17.71878,
        "model_confidence": 1.0,
        "image_resolution": "7427 * 2623",
        "checksum_status": true
    },
    "info": {
        "name": [
            "V",
            "Parameswaran"
        ],
        "date_of_birth": {
            "date": 28,
            "month": 12,
            "year": 1989
        },
        "aadhaar_id": "4682********",
        "gender": "male",
        "address": [
            "Unique Identification Authority of India C/O",
            "316 / 87",
            "*******",
            "*******",
            "***********",
            "*******",
            "*****"
        ],
        "state": null,
        "pincode": null
       }
    }
  }
```

AAdhar model 1 class:

```
  import Foundation

 public struct aadharModels: Codable {

let id: String
let info: infoAadharClass

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case links = "_links"
        case info = "info"
        case id
    }
 }

 struct infoAadharClass: Codable {

let aadhaar_id, gender: String
let name: [String]
let dateofbirth: DobClass
let address: [String]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case aadhaar_id, gender
    case name
    case address
    case dateofbirth = "date_of_birth"
}
}

struct DobClass: Codable {

 let date, month, year: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

       case date, month, year
   }
}
```

Here the code where i am passing aadhar model 1 to aadhar model2:

```
  let aadharID = data.info.aadhaar_id
                     let aadharB_Day = data.info.dateofbirth.date
                     let aadharB_month = data.info.dateofbirth.month
                     let aadharB_year = data.info.dateofbirth.year
                     let aadharGender = data.info.gender
                     let aadharName = data.info.name
                     let aadharAddress = data.info.address
                     print("aadhar address", aadharAddress)

  let aadharDate = aadharB_Day+"/"+aadharB_month+"/"+aadharB_year

                     var aadhar_c = AadharModelConverted(aadharNumber: aadharID, dob: aadharDate, gender: aadharGender, name: aadharAddress, address: aadharAddress)

     //convert to json
      let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(aadhar_c)
                        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
                        print("json object using pan model",jsonString)
```

Here is aadhar model 2:

```
        import Foundation

 public struct AadharModelConverted: Codable {

var aadharNumber: String?
var dob: String?
var gender: String?
var name: [String]?
var address: addressSubclass_c

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case aadharNumber, dob, gender, name
    case address = "address"
  }

 }

struct addressSubclass_c: Codable {

var values: [String]

 }
```

Json output i'm trying to get:

```
 {
 "aadharNumber": "60**********",
 "dob": "0/0/1994",
 "gender": "male",
 "name": "VipinAgrawal",
 "address": {
 "values": [
  "S/O Mukesh Agrawal",
  "ho",
  "no - 67",
  "******",
  "******",
  "******"
   ]
  }
 }
```

Any help much appreciated pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your initial **`Codable`** models to parse the actual *JSON* should be like,

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id: String
    let data: AadharData

    var formattedModel: AadharModelConverted {
        var model = AadharModelConverted()
        model.aadharNumber = self.data.info.aadhaarId
        model.dob = String(describing: self.data.info.dateOfBirth)
        model.gender = self.data.info.gender
        model.name = self.data.info.name
        model.address?.values = self.data.info.address
        return model
    }
}

struct AadharData: Codable {
    let info: AadharInfo
}

struct AadharInfo: Codable {
    let aadhaarId, gender: String
    let name: [String]
    let dateOfBirth: DOB
    let address: [String]
}

struct DOB: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let date, month, year: Int

    var description: String {
        return "\(date)/\(month)/\(year)"
    }
}
```

In the above models,

**1.** `struct Root` contains a computed property `formattedModel` that will return a model of type `AadharModelConverted`

**2.** Conform `struct DOB` to `CustomStringConvertible` and override `description` to return the expected `String` value.

```
struct AadharModelConverted: Codable {
    var aadharNumber: String?
    var dob: String?
    var gender: String?
    var name: [String]?
    var address: Address?
}

struct Address: Codable {
    var values: [String]
}
```

You can now parse the *JSON* data using,

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let model = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

let formattedModel = model.formattedModel

let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(formattedModel)
let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(str)
```